# Why do BTs leave handprints when they move?

Tags: death-stranding

When BTs are moving around they leave handprints on the ground. We see this most clearly in the initial cave cutscene.

However, it’s also evident in every other encounter with BTs; they’ve left handprints on Sam, when they rush Sam hands come out of the ground and when destroyed they leave chiral crystals which are sort of hand shaped.

But, we see that BTs are normal things from our world and stand upright.

[image: Sam crouches with cargo on his back, up ahead we see a BT; human stood in t-pose with its cord spiralling down to the ground]

So, why do they leave handprints on the ground when they move?